# C++ conditional execution depending on the type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template function that should execute different code, depends on the type. The simplified function looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::string test(T value)
{
    std::string v;
    if(std::is_arithmetic<T>())
    {
        v = std::to_string(value);
    }
    else
    {
       v = std::string(value);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
test("Hello");
test(123);
```

But I get this error:

```cpp
In instantiation of void test(T) [with T = const char*]:
error: no matching function for call to to_string(const char*)
note: candidate: std::string std::__cxx11::to_string(int) <near match>
to_string(int __val)

and the same for the following:

to_string(unsigned __val)
to_string(long __val)
to_string(unsigned long __val)
```

Ok, I understand that in case of, for example `const char *` the compilation will fail since there  is no `std::to_string(const char *)`. but how can I do the code works? Just have to note that in my real code I limit to `c++11`.

Comment: `if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic<T>())`. If you can't use it, you would need use SFINAE and two different templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply overloading with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). E.g.

```
// for arithmetic types
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::string>::type test(T value)
{
    std::string v;
    v = std::to_string(value);
    return v;
}

// for non-arithmetic types
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::string>::type test(T value)
{
    std::string v;
    v = std::string(value);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Ok, looks that SFINAE is the optimal solution for my case although I don't really like this 'templates tricks' instead of normal introspection. I am grateful for this decision @songyuanyao

Comment: c++20 cleans this up with `requires` instead of SFINAE

Answer (score 5):

You now get a taste of why `if constexpr` was added to the language. If you need to perform some type-dependent operation as part of your larger algorithm, then in pre-C++17 the way to do that is typically via [*tag-dispatch*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Tag_Dispatching)

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    std::string stringify(T value, std::true_type) {
        return std::to_string(value);
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::string stringify(T value, std::false_type) {
        return std::string(value);
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::string test(T value)
{
    std::string v;
    v = detail::stringify(value, std::is_arithmetic<T>());
    return v;
}
```

This is dispatching on two conditions, but the technique can be expanded to multiple overloads, depending on how you construct your tag types. A common example in the standard is [iterator categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags).

Comment: Yes, it would be great if I wasn't limited with c++11, we work with gcc 4.8.2 so features from C++17 aren't available, to our regret.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the part where it checks if it's an integer or not:

```
// essentially the center of the code
    if (std::is_arithmetic<T>())
    {
        v = std::to_string(value);
    }
    else
    {
       v = std::string(value);
    }
```

If you're using <= C++17, you could easily use `if constexpr()`, but you're not.

I would also suggest using `SFINAE` or tag-disspatch

Answer (score 0):

If you want something available in C++11 and closer to your original attempt, you can use `conditional_t` with helper functors (one for arithmetic types and one for not)

```cpp
namespace helper
{
template<typename T>
struct ARITHMETIC
{
    std::string operator()(T x)
    {
        return std::to_string(x);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct NON_ARITHMETIC
{
    std::string operator()(T x)
    {
        return std::string(x);
    }
};
}

template <class T>
std::string test(T value)
{
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,
        helper::ARITHMETIC<T>,
        helper::NON_ARITHMETIC<T>>::type convert;

    return convert(value);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << test("Hello") << std::endl;
    std::cout << test(123) << std::endl;
}
```